# How to increase memory size for downloadHandler in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

When running Shiny, I get the message that "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" when the download function is called. It works when the data file is smaller; but all of the tables combined should be less than 5,000 rows and 15 columns for the instance I'm looking at. Can someone help me make my downloadHandler functional with this kind of file size?

```
*# server.R*

library(XLConnect)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  ... (filtering operation on a data frame to create multiple sub tables)

  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(

    filename = function() {paste(input$category,"_raw_token_data.xlsx")},

    content = function(file){
      fname <- paste(file,"xlsx",sep=".")
      wb <- loadWorkbook(fname, create = TRUE)
      createSheet(wb, name = "-terms")
      createSheet(wb, name = "+terms")
      createSheet(wb, name = "-tokens")
      createSheet(wb, name = "+tokens")
      createSheet(wb, name = "test_stats")
      writeWorksheet(wb, raw()$filter_neg, sheet = "-terms") 
      writeWorksheet(wb, raw()$filter_kw, sheet = "+terms") 
      writeWorksheet(wb, df()$neg_raw, sheet = "-tokens") 
      writeWorksheet(wb, df()$rel_raw, sheet = "+tokens") 
      writeWorksheet(wb, df()$test_raw, sheet = "test_stats") 
      saveWorkbook(wb)
      file.rename(fname,file)
    }

  ) # closing for downloadHandler

}) # closing for shinyServer
```

**Solution:**

```
options(java.parameters = "-Xmx1g") # increase heap size to 1gb
library(RWeka)
```

Comment: Have you tried setting JVM options before you call `library(XLConnect)`. For example setting `options(java.parameters = "-Xmx1024m")`?

Comment: @jdharrison thanks for the reply. I tried this code without success. Is there another function in Shiny that allows xlsx output or is the best way to write csv tables zipped into a folder?

Comment: @jdharrison actually increasing the parameter to 1g helped. thanks for the tip!